# Grammatik in "als wäre sie des Tempos dann irgendwann nicht mehr Herr geworden"

Tags: grammar, word-order, genitive

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Von außen betrachtet, wirkt Jolies Leben jedenfalls gehetzt. Als versuchte sie wettzumachen, was sie in jungen Jahren versäumt hat, und **als wäre sie des Tempos dann irgendwann nicht mehr Herr geworden.**

Ich glaube, der fette Teil ist äquivalent zu

> als wäre sie dann irgendwann nicht mehr **Herr des Tempos** geworden.

Aber warum kann man *des Tempos* weit nach vorne stellen? Was ist hier die Regel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das liegt daran, dass "einer Sache Herr werden" (und in der Tat nicht "Herr einer Sache werden") zu einer feststehenden Wendung geworden ist. Für mich persönlich fühlt sich das "Herr" dabei gar nicht mehr wie ein Substantiv an, sondern das gesamte Konstrukti wie "einer Sache müde werden", obwohl der grammatische Ursprung ein anderer ist. (Zuerst hatte ich hier "gerecht" statt "müde", aber boaten hat richtig darauf hingewiesen, dass dann "einer Sache" Dativ statt Genitiv ist.)

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung. Ich möchte noch bemerken, dass "einer Sache" in "einer Sache Herr werden" Genitiv ist, in "einer Sache gerecht werden" aber Dativ ist. Ist das richtig?

Comment: Hoppla, das war mir gar nicht aufgefallen. Dann ist das vielleicht ein schlechter Vergleich...

Comment: Trotzdem sehr interessant. Lassen wir uns sehen, was die anderen zu sagen haben. :)

Comment: @boaten... off topic: für "Let's do xy" sprichst du normalerweise deinen Dialogpartner an. Also 2. Person singular imperative "Lass uns....". Wenn du mehrere Leute ansprechen willst, so gruppenmässig, dann benutzt man Plural Imperativ "Lasst und ..." Aber nie mit "wir". Es gibt ja schließlich in einer Aufforderung kein Subjekt.

Comment: @Emanuel Danke ;)